# ssh access to ec2 from php

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh, amazon-ec2

From local ubuntu linux machine connecting ec2 machine by ssh access.

when i run this php script from terminal it executes fine and write the tailed entries in file. when i run from browser got this error in apache error log

**ssh: Could not resolve hostname proxy2: Name or service not known**

Found its due to apache user permission problem. whether my guess is right or wrong am not sure. Any one helps me to fix this issue.

php code:-

```
<?php

$ss = 'ssh proxy2 '.'tail -n 3 /out/speed_log.txt.1'.' > proxy2temp1';
system($ss);
?>
```

Comment: Does the apache user have permission to write the proxy2temp1 file? Also, are you sure the error message is correct? I don't see anywhere a 'proxy23' hostname, only a 'proxy2'.

Comment: If you type that ssh command into your command line, can you connect successfully? It seems to be that your machine doesn't where proxy2 is or what its IP address is?

Comment: sam am typed wrong as proxy23

Comment: james i can able to connect from command line. when i run php script from terminal this php executes fines. when i try to execute by apache the error thrown like this...

Comment: @MohanShanmugam, is it possible you have a `proxy2` entry with `Hostname` in ~/.ssh/config? That would explain an other user (apache) not being able to resolve `proxy2`

Comment: I doubt it's a permissions issue, since ssh isn't complaining about permissions. It can't resolve `proxy2` to an IP address, which means the browser environment is using a different DNS resolver configuration than your command line environment.

Comment: Using the ssh2 extension (available in PECL, doc: http://ca3.php.net/ssh2) would provide with more control in handling errors. It's also faster and more reliable than going through the shell.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally found an solution using phpseclib and solved my problem. am recommend phpseclib to connect amazon ec2 machines from php uing .pem file to help others share my sample code.

make sure .pem file needs permission to read**

**sample code:**

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();

$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('/pathtokey.pem'));


$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
if (!$ssh->login('user', $key)) {
exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('tail -n 3 /out/_log.txt.1');
```

Comment: after you SSH into the instance, how can you make a http request?